# image magick: right align text in area

Tags: text, scripting, image-manipulation, imagemagick, alignment

i'm struggling with this:
i'm building a table-like image.
All goes well, but i can't get this to work:
i want to place some text at x,y: 10,10, but want to right align it in an area of 40x40.
Why? because they are numbers. When i draw text it's ok to place it at 10,10; it will by default be placed at 10,10 and thus be left-aligned.
But i have some numbers which i want to 'right-align'. The next 'column' starts at X position 55, so i want to reserve some kind of imaginary region from x=10 to x=50 (to keep some margin to the next column) and draw the text from right to left at 10,50.

I found the geometry option and the region, but my trial and errors didn't give me any good results.

Michel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-gravity` to the rescue, check the [documentation with examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#text_gravity).

**Update**: OK I misunderstood the task.

But IMHO you can still create your numbers as an image first (of course you can customize the font, etc) and trim it:

```
/usr/bin/convert -fill black -size 40x40 label:$NUMBERS -transparent white -trim  numbers.gif
```

Now check the new image's size

```
/usr/bin/identify trimmed.gif
```

Then calculate where to position it on your image. I leave it to you ;-)

Now you only need to merge the numbers to your image to the perfect position (replace +X+Y).

```
/usr/bin/composite -geometry +X+Y trimmed.gif original_image.jpg original_with_numbers.jpg
```

HTH

Comment: didn't mention it, but tried gravity too.
All the examples are with a single image, say gravity -east for the entire image. I want to todo this in a PART of the image

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it really helped me. You can save a step by using `-trim` in the first command, i.e. `convert -fill black -size 40x40 label:$NUMBERS -transparent white -trim trimmed.gif`